# Cannot Install or Update Using apt-get with VirtualBox

Tags: networking, apt, updates, virtualbox

I'm having a problem installing or updating anything from the command line in Ubuntu in VirtualBox. My host computer is running Mac OS X Snow Leopard (because my Mac is old), my virtual computer is running Ubuntu 14.10 and I'm running VirtualBox 4.0.36 (again, because my Mac is old).

I'm trying to run Java on my virtual machine, but it seems that I can't do that without the command line. Every time I try to install via the command line, I get an error of "Unable to locate package." If I try to run `sudo apt-get update`, I'll get a series of 404 errors. In my research, I've found that it could be a network error that is causing my problem. However, I am able to access the Internet and Ubuntu Software Center normally, which leads me to think that the network is not the issue. Just in case, however, I'll mention that my virtual machine is attached to a Bridged Adapter.

I've done a lot of searching, but I can't find a solution that seems to answer my specific problem. Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is no longer supported. Use 14.04 or 15.10.

Comment: Okay. Will that fix my problem?

Comment: That will fix the 404 erorrs, at least.

Comment: That fully fixed my problem! The only reason that I was running 14.10 in the first place is that someone said that it would make VirtualBox run faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the 404 errors was that Ubuntu 14.10 has already reached its end of life. When an Ubuntu releases reaches EOL, its packages are moved from the normal Ubuntu archive morrors to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/. Hence, when one tries to get the packages from the normal mirrors, they are not found and a 404 error is triggered.

The correct thing to do is to use an Ubuntu release which has not reached EOL, such as 14.04 or 15.10 currently, but if it absolutely necessary to use the EOL releases, one must modify the `sources.list` file to obtain packages from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/.